# Why do a lot of JavaScript libraries have a z-index of 1051?

Tags: javascript, css, z-index

Why most of Javascript Libraries and even frameworks set to some of their elements z-index 1051? Why exactly 1051?

Am I wrong if I set z-index 1052 to some element I need to overlay the first one?

Comment: Which JS libraries are you referring to?

Comment: Jquery UI, Bootstrap, Select2, Zurb Foundation

Comment: It is neatly just above 1050.

Comment: Ok, why 1050?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I wrong if I set z-index 1052 to some element I need to overlay the first one?

This question can't be answered with yes or no. It depends on the Stacking Context, your Element is part of. The property `z-index` works perfectly fine within its own Stacking context, but if there are two elements in different Contexts, it does not matter if you set the `z-index` to 0, 100 or 9999. There are multiple scenerios, where a new stacking context is created, for example if an element has `position: absolute` or `relative`. Also setting an `opacity` creates an entire new stacking context. To learn more about stacking contexts, read this [Documentation Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context).

Unfortunally, I don't know, why its set to `1051` in the Libraries you mentioned, but at least I can tell you, why `z-index; 1052` will propably won't work.

**Edit:**
I googled a bit, because I find this question is at least interesting, even if it does not fit the SO rules. Seems like Bootstrap Modals have a z-index of 1050, so every element, that propably has to overlay the modal itself, has to have an higher z-index. This only leads to the question, why modals have a z-index of 1050.

[Here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/e38f066d8c203c3e032da0ff23cd2d6098ee2dd6/less/variables.less#L272-L278) is a link to the `z-index` specifications of bootstrap. As you can see, they start at `1000`, and increase the `z-index` by `10` for every element, that has to overlap the previous one, so **I guess** it is just kind of a Bootstrap Code Convention, which has a cascading effect at other libraries. Or Bootstrap did it because of a library it uses itself. Now we have kind of an "Hen egg question".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about Stacking Context and I have only two. I am just used to wonder why some things made the way they are. Maybe developers have studied a lot to make this z-index precisely 1050 and I am not so arrogant to overcome it with the higher level just after thinking for a while.

Answer (score 0):

This is to ensure that these "some elements" overlay surrounding content. It starts at 1000+ to give you space in case you are using `z-index` yourself (0 to xxx degits).

Comment: So does it mean that I would surely not have more than 999 layers in my own scripts?

Comment: Not really. It is just about "having space" for further development. I myself use some of these libraries and use `z-index:0-20`,  `z-index:500+` and `z-index:3000+` on my own elements just in case in the future, the users want some things that might come in between. :)